# How to make a curved fill in SVG

Tags: svg, fill

I can make half an arc like this:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <path d="
      M 50, 100
      m 25, 0
      a 25,25 0 1,0 -50,0" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="10px" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

If I try to make that into a fill, it ends up just filling in the half of the arc, rather than filling in the stroke/line around the arc.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <path d="
      M 50, 100
      m 25, 0
      a 25,25 0 1,0 -50,0" fill="#000" width="10px" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I would like to be able to draw a fill the same shape as the stroke, so I can taper the end of the "stroke" in custom ways to look like a real pen stroke.

[image]

Not only would I like to make it like that pen stroke, I would want to have full control over the shape of the so-called "fill-stroke" so it can be however I'd like. So it can be tapered like that, or it can be bubbly, or however. Basically I don't want it to be a stroke, but instead a fill, so I can have more control over it. Wondering how to accomplish that.

Comment: Helpful: tutorial on path drawing commands in SVG: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Comment: [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) has a ["Calligraphy"](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Creating.html#Paths-Calligraphy) feature that helps you with hand-drawn lines. For a more construction-like approach, you could first draw by hand, then simplify the path (another automatic feature), than tweak the result by changing the (envelope) path. Another tool is [Stroke to Path](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Creating.html#Stroke-To-Path), where you start out with a normal path and then can deform it.

Comment: I just found a third approach I wasn't aware of yet: [Pattern Along Path](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-PatternAlongPath.html). Define your "stroke width" along a straight horizontal path and then re-apply it to a curved path. Very neat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 200" width="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <path d="
      M 50, 100
      m 25, 0
      a 25,25 0 1,0 -50,0
      h 10
      A20,20 0 0,1 75,100z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: That is cool! Thank you. But I would like to do it without using stroke if possible :)

Comment: I'm sorry for the `stroke-width="10px"`. I've deleted it. I'm not using stroke.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works. Would help if you wouldn't mind explaining how it works. Going to read up on the A command some more I guess.

Comment: You begin moving to x=50, y= 100. Next you move to x = 50 + 25, y = 100. (This is from your code). You may have moved directly to x = 75, y=100. Lowercase is for relative coordinates. Then you draw an elliptical arc (`a` command) that begins at the last point, i.e x=75, y=100. The ellipse radius are rx=ry=25, you go counterclockwise to x=75-50, y=100. The `h` command is for horizontal lines, in this case you go to x = 25 + 10. The y is the same. Lastly you draw an other arc `A` using absolute coordinates. Radiuses are rx=ry=20, you go clockwise and you go back at the starting point x=75.y=100.